# Python is omitting special characters in a script that transfers data between two databases

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql

The first database is MySQL and the second one is Postgresql.

I am transferring the following string:

```
a ≥ b
```

After the process is complete, the Postgresql column shows:

```
a = b
```

The first column is an nvarchar, the Postgresql column is a varchar. If I manually change the field in Postgresql and save 'a ≥ b', this will remain there, but my data transfer reverts it back to 'a = b' which makes me believe it's the python script.

Here are some snippets from the script:

```
format_trans = {
'bigint' : 'int',
'int': 'int',
'dt': 'dt',
'dt_tz': 'dt',
'ts': 'ts',
'bool': 'bool',
'tinybool': 'bool',
'tinyint': 'tinyint',
'varchar': 'str',
'float': 'int',
'decimal': 'Decimal',
'numeric': 'int',
'dp': 'float',
'guid': 'guid',
'text': 'str',
'int_or_null': 'int_or_null',
'exempt_id': 'exempt_id',
'default_empty_str': 'default_empty_str',
'datetime': 'Date',
'smallint': 'int',
'booltoint': 'booltoint',
'uniqueidentifier' : 'guid',
'nvarchar': 'str',
```

}

```
def value_generator(self, cols):
    rows = []
    col_map = self.job['col_map']
    for row in self.data:
        vlist = []
        for column in cols:
            from_col_row = [tpl for tpl in col_map if tpl[1] == column][0]
            from_col = from_col_row[0].lower() #pyodbc lowers column names
            # if from_col[0:12] == '__fixedcol__':
            #     val = from_col[12:]
            #     logging.info("****STUFF: " + val)
            #else:
            vtype = format_trans[from_col_row[2]]
            if vtype == "int_or_null":
                val = None if row[from_col] == 0 else row[from_col]
            elif vtype in ['guid']:
                val = str(row[from_col])
                if val[:2] == "b'":
                    val = val[2:len(val) - 1]
            elif vtype == 'dt' or vtype == 'Date':
                val = None if row[from_col] == '' else row[from_col]
            elif vtype == 'exempt_id':
                val = 0 if row[from_col] == 3 else row[from_col]
            elif vtype == 'default_empty_str':
                val = '' if (row[from_col] == None or row[from_col] == '') else row[from_col]
            elif vtype == 'tinybool':
                val = True if row[from_col] == 1 else False
            elif vtype == 'tinyint':
                val = 1 if row[from_col] else 0
            else:
                s = from_col
                if s[0] == '[':  
                    s = ''.join([x for x in s if x not in '[]'])
                val = row[s]
            vlist.append(val)

        rows.append(tuple(vlist))
    return rows
```

So I'm not an expert in Python. If in the formatting, I create a special case for 'nvarchar' (other than 'str'), how would I transfer this to make sure it doesn't strip any special characters ?

Comment: Can you try adding the line   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-  at the top of your script?

Comment: If you print the value in the script, before writing to Postgres, what is it?  (Since there may be an issue with the display of the character, per your previous questions, please call `chr` on the character and print that too).